# How to convert int to NSString?

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to convert an `int` to a `NSString` in Objective C.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 158):

Primitives can be converted to objects with `@()` expression. So the **shortest** way is to transform `int` to [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and pick up string representation with [`stringValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/stringValue) method:

```
NSString *strValue = [@(myInt) stringValue];
```

or

```
NSString *strValue = @(myInt).stringValue;
```

Comment: Slightly less verbose: `NSString *strValue = @(myInt).stringValue;`

Comment: @DielsonSales some objects don't have `stringValue`, but all have `description` - so as a good practice it's better to get used to using `description` (`NSNumber` does, no need to worry here). Try this (`description` will print the date, but `stringValue` will crash): `NSNumber *test = (id)[NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"description:  %@", test.description);
    NSLog(@"string value: %@", test.stringValue);
`

Comment: @IslamQ. `@(myInt)` is a [boxed expression](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-expressions) for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` and it will always return an NSNumber when given an int. `[NSNumber stringValue]` will always return an NSString. In the code of your comment, force casting with `(id)` and assigning to a different type is a clear programming mistake: you should never do that. It's like swizzling a method and then making an argument about that method not doing what it was originally doing.

Comment: @IslamQ. Try converting your comment to Swift without using the crash operator (`!`) and you'll figure out that you were doing it wrongly in Objective-C. If the object `test` wasn't created by you, then it's not your responsibility. You may attempt to call `isKindOfClass:` for all your received parameters, but even that can be fooled (by passing a struct instead of an NSObject for instance). So don't do it: just document explicitly the expected types.

Comment: @Cœur, of course casting an object to `(id)` is a mistake, it was just to demo the point that IMO `description` is preferred over `stringValue` (I may be wrong, haven't programmed in ObjC for years)

Comment: @IslamQ. `NSNumber *test = (__bridge id)(void*)1; NSLog(@"%@", test.description);` will still crash. Or include `@implementation NSDate(foo)-(NSString *)description{exit(0);}@end` in the same file as your code with `[NSDate date]` and it will crash when calling description. Or overrelease your date and it may crash unpredictably when calling description (`CFDateRef date=CFDateCreate(nil, 0);CFRelease(date);NSNumber*test=CFBridgingRelease(date);NSLog(@"%@",test.description);`). Lastly, the output of your description may not crash but it's more likely to be inconsistent across OS updates.

Answer (score 146):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", theinteger];
```

Comment: @Elist when you know the primitive type, I wonder if there may be slightly less overhead by avoiding the intermediate NSNumber from your code? `@(myInt)` is a [boxed expression](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-expressions), it returns an NSNumber.

Answer (score 38):

```
int i = 25;
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
```

This is one of many ways.

Answer (score 2):

If this string is for presentation to the end user, you should use [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html). This will add thousands separators, and will honor the localization settings for the user:

```
NSInteger n = 10000;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(n)];
```

In the US, for example, that would create a string `10,000`, but in Germany, that would be `10.000`.