# Objective C Convert int to NSString (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, int

I have the following code that is meant to convert milliseconds into hours, mins and seconds:

```
int hours = floor(rawtime / 3600000);

int mins = floor((rawtime % 3600000) / (1000 * 60));
int secs = floor(((rawtime % 3600000) % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

NSLog(@"%d:%d:%d", hours, mins, secs);

NSString *hoursStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", hours];
NSString *minsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mins];
NSString *secsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", secs];

NSLog(@"%a:%a:%a", hoursStr, minsStr, secsStr);
```

Fairly straightforward. Rawtime is an int with value 1200. The output is like this:

```
0:0:1

0x1.3eaf003d9573p-962:0x1.7bd2003d3ebp-981:-0x1.26197p-698
```

Why is it that converting the ints to strings gives such wild numbers? I've tried using %i and %u and they made no difference. What is happening?

Comment: Duplicate(?) of [how to convert from int to string in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372715/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string-in-iphone)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use `%@` as the conversion specifier for an NSString.  Change your last line to:

```
NSLog(@"%@:%@:%@", hoursStr, minsStr, secsStr);
```

`%a` means something totally different.  From the `printf()` [man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/printf.3.html):

> **aA**
> The double argument is rounded and converted to hexadecimal notation in the style
>
> ```
> [-]0xh.hhhp[+-]d
> ```
>
> where the number of digits after the hexadecimal-point character is equal to the precision specification.

Comment: Ah I knew it would be something simple that I missed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of rolling your own string formatting code, you should be using an [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for numbers or an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for dates/times. These data formatters take care of localization of format to the user's locale and handle a variety of formats built-in.

For your use, you need to convert your millisecond time into an `NSTimeInterval` (`typedef`'d from a double):

```
NSTimeInterval time = rawtime/1e3;
```

Now you can use an `NSDateFormatter` to present the time:

```
NSDate *timeDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:time];
NSString *formattedTime = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:timeDate
                                                         dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle 
                                                         timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *rawTime = [[formattedTime componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
```

on OS X where the last line removes the "AM/PM". This will work for any time less than 12 hrs and will give a formatted string in the localized format for HH:MM:SS. On the iPhone, `localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:` isn't available (yet). You can achieve the same effect with `setTimeStyle:`, `setDateStyle:` and `stringFromDate:` on a date formatter instance.

Comment: Is localizedStringFromDate available on iphone?  Maybe have to use setLocale instead?

Comment: @DyingCactus You're absolutely correct; `localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle` isn't available on iPhone (yet). You can achieve the same functionality using `setDateStyle:` and `setTimeStyle` followed by `stringFromDate:`