# Changing variable from int to string

Tags: ios, variables, replace

Good morning,
First of all excuse me for my english.
A partner has made an app that place an image in the ios display depending the placement id you write on a textfield. He defined the textfield and the variable as a integer, but when he finished he realized that it should be an string. Now its all coded for a int, is there an easy way to parse it to string?

Comment: NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%d", YourIntVariable];

Comment: @rmaddy : Of course, it is caused by my haste

Answer (score 0):

See this other SO question: [How can I convert an int to an NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372715/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string-in-iphone)

In short, with the code `NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", theinteger];`

Comment: Im sorry, my english is not perfect and its hard to find a related question. Thank you for the answer

Comment: @mjkaufer Instead of linking an answer to a duplicate, you should vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
int yourIntVar = ??;
NSString *intIntoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", yourIntVar];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
myTextfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myInt];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 2;
NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",num];
```