# Count objects in array for string

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have an array stored in Parse and I wanted to count the objects in the array and then display that number in a label. I have been able to count the objects but for some reason can not figure out how to turn it into a string. Here is my code:

```
    cell.CheckinLabel.text = (@"count = %d", [[imageObject objectForKey:@"Checkin"] count]);
    NSLog(@"count = %d", [[imageObject objectForKey:@"Checkin"] count]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372715/how-can-i-convert-an-int-to-an-nsstring

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[imageObject objectForKey:@"Checkin"] count]];
yourlabel.text = string;
```

Or,

```
yourlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[imageObject objectForKey:@"Checkin"] count]];
```