# XCODE 5 Core Data returning integer to label

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Just asking about this one line of code which is causing my app to crash

```
cell.yearLabel.text = [entityObject valueForKey:@"year"];
```

the label is in a custom cell I've made I want to pass a year from core data e.g. 1977 to this label however I believe the value needs to be a string when the value is an integer. If I'm incorrect or theres a way to change the value to a string I'd very much appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Xcode 5, really? You need to update to the latest tools for the sake of the users of your app.

Comment: unfortunately my university only allows the use of Xcode 5 :(!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert an int to an NSString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372715/how-can-i-convert-an-int-to-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that if the value is always an Integer, you can simply do :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[entityObject valueForKey:@"year"]]
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was after! Thank you man saved me a lot of hassle!